# Heuristics for search nodes instead of states?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, shortest-path, a-star, heuristics

When reading about AI (A*) and heuristics I encountered this statement:

```
Heuristics are sometimes defined for search nodes instead of states,
but this increased generality is rarely useful. (Why?)
```

Can someone explain what is meant by this, give an example and also answer to the Why? question?

Comment: From this document: http://ai.cs.unibas.ch/_files/teaching/fs16/ai/slides/ai13.pdf

Answer (score 0):

When using heuristics you mainly making the search for the goal state **less exhausting**. The statement here relies on the difference between a node and a state.

Suppose you have a game in which you can be in a different states by just changing an actor (e.x. sokoban).https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sokoban

To implement a-star you must realize that you are searching in a graph in which

> **each node is a possible state of the game.**

A node represent a state and holds a specific function f(x) where

`f(x)= g(x)+h(x)`

and h(x) is admissible.
Here **h(x)** will give a better approach on how far the goal state is because **you are able** to calculate distance based on the goal (*ex. Manhattan distance*).Particularly you apply Manhattan distance on the nearest box or the nearest target.

This set of attributes in states, **define** the heuristic cost thus making the search less exhausting.  If the search is not made based on the attributes of the state for the particular game then heuristic is not useful in advance.